# Is tauri deep link plugin working on linux?

Tags: linux, tauri

I am trying to create Tauri desktop app with Auth0. It is working on Windows but when tried it on Ubuntu 22.04 gives me message "Redirection to URL with a scheme that is not HTTP(S)Redirection to URL with a scheme that is not HTTP(S)". Is problem in the plugin or in my setup.

This is mine main.rs

```
#![cfg_attr(all(not(debug_assertions)), windows_subsystem = "windows")]
use tauri::Manager;

fn main() {
    tauri_plugin_deep_link::prepare("com.deep-linking.test");
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .setup(|app| {
            let handle = app.handle();
            tauri_plugin_deep_link::register("tauri", move |request| {
                dbg!(&request);
                handle.emit_all("scheme-request-received", request).unwrap();
            })
            .unwrap();
            Ok(())
        })
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

I use react for the frontend. In the place of my domian and client id I have Auth0 credentials there.
main.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import "./style.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Auth0Provider
      domain="my domian"
      clientId="my clinet id"
      authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
      }}
    >
      <App />
    </Auth0Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.jsx

```
import "./App.css";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
function App() {
  const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

  return <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}>Log In</button>;
}

export default App;
```